# Should I include the article I co-authored in my resume?

Tags: publications, cv

I studied a specific topic with my professor in the intern researcher scholarship program in college. One of my friends also was helping me. He was planning to become the professor's research assistant, and in the meantime, was helping when he had his free time. I prepared an 18-page document and conference paper. After that, we continued with the same industry, but he continued academics, and I continued on the field. Then, he started a master's degree and became a research assistant. His topic decided as the expand the current work we worked on make it more and more detailed. Last year, his paper was published, and thanks to him, he added me as co-author.

Now, one of my plans is to continue on the academic. Should I put the published articles on my resume? If it is yes, how should I put it?

Since I am continuing in the field, my experience and knowledge about academics are low in my current situation. That's why, If this question is an absurd one, I would love to know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations on your publication!

And yes, absolutely, do put it in your CV! Academics typically have a subsection "publications", possibly even as a separate document. Especially if you have been around for a while, this can become quite long. However, at the beginning of your academic career, it might make sense to have it as a subsection of your "general" CV, unless wherever you submit it requests a separate list of publications.

I personally format this list in exactly the same way as a list of references in any paper, but in descending order of publication date, so the most recent one is the first one. Also, depending on your field, how many co-authors there usually are and whether the position in the list of authors is relevant, it may make sense to typeset your name in **bold**.

Comment: I agree and yes, put your name in bold. Your coauthor's name will come first.

Comment: Yes, publication lists can become quite long.  My father has almost 1000 scientific publications.  He just links to an online list of them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, list any publication in your field for which you are an author. Even fairly closely related fields work for this.

A CV normally has a *Publications* section, generally near the top.

Only if the publication is wildly out of field would I not list it. I actually have rather diverse publications (and am working on another) and won't list a few of them on my CV for anything related to math or CS.

The CV is intended to highlight your accomplishments in the field as this surely does.

Comment: Why would you not add a particular paper to a CV? Surely it's more important to show a track record rather than picking and choosing (assuming you're not an academic with 50+ publications under your belt)? Plus, even a publication completely unrelated to your chosen field demonstrates that you can go through a peer review process successfully, right?

Comment: @isolatedmatrix To give examples to exclude publications from a professional CV: Donald Knuth's 3:16 Bible Texts Illuminated. Or if you publish your hobby as cyclist, dog breeder, Lego brick builder, report to your local newspaper from comic con.

Comment: @usr1234567 I'm not sure I would consider an article in your 'local newspaper' a 'paper', or a book about religion... In case I wasn't clear, I was asking about why someone might not include an *academic article* in a CV, assuming it's not saturated with articles already.